# Ruby delete_if multiple values - only first value being deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
words.delete_if do |x|
  x == ("a"||"for"||"to"||"and")
end
```

`words` is an array with many words. My code is deleting "a" but not deleting "for", "to" or "and".

Comment: FWIW, the logic you were going for would be expressed as `x == 'a' || x == 'for' || x == 'to' || x == 'and'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do

```
words - ["a", "for", "to", "and"]
```

Example

```
words = %w(this is a just test data for array - method and nothing)
 => ["this", "is", "a", "just", "test", "data", "for", "array", "-", "method", "and", "nothing"] 
words = words - ["a", "for", "to", "and"]
 => ["this", "is", "just", "test", "data", "array", "-", "method", "nothing"]
```

Answer (score 8):

May this will help you

```
words.delete_if do |x|
  %w(a for to and).include?(x)
end
```

Answer (score 5):

If you run "a" || "b" in irb then you will always get "a" because it is a non null value and it would be returned by || always..
In your case "a"||"for" will always evaluate for "a" irrespective of the other values in the array..
So this is my alternate solution to your question

w = %W{a for to end}

words.reject! { |x| w.include?(x) }